# Postgres: Regexpr for line break

Tags: postgresql

We have in our DB a string for HTML CSS. One of the attributes has in the DB column `css_html` the value

```
other-format.....
font-family: 'Liberatio
Sans'
additional-other-formats
```

this causes a problem since there is a line break included. I want to have the `\n` (=line break) removed to look like

```
other-format.....
font-family: 'Liberatio Sans'
additional-other-formats
```

I have no clue how to even select properly all values. If I try something like

```
select * from css_content c 
where c.css_html similar to 'font-name:[.]*\n'
```

I don't even get selected the effected rows. Any idea how to replace the string with a single select?

Answer (score 0):

In first, an escape string constant is specified by writing the letter E (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote, e.g., E'foo'
[4.1.2.2. String Constants with C-style Escapes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

`similar to E'font-name:[.]*\n'`

In second pattern incorrect.

Comment: And how would be the replace syntax to get rid of the line break?

Comment: The key is regexp. Sorry.